# Fastest way to merge columns of the same type in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, performance

Say I have a numpy array `A` that records the distances from **different** 1D points. The first column records the coordinate of each destination point, the second column records the pairwise distances. Now I want to construct a distance matrix `D` that records the pairwise distances (rows correspond to source points, columns correspond to destination points, the distance will be recorded as infinite if unknown). This should be easy, but becomes tricky when there are duplicate destination points. Below is a simple example: I have two points with the coordinate 2.5, and two points with the coordinate 6.1. I tried using `np.unique` to get the unique columns, but when there are duplicates, it picks the first-appeared distance and lose the distance information of the other pairs

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[7.3, 0.25],
              [2.5, 0.32],
              [3.7, 0.45],
              [6.1, 0.55],
              [2.5, 0.91],
              [4.8, 0.77],
              [8.6, 0.35],
              [6.1, 0.82]])
D = np.ones((A.shape[0],A.shape[0])) * np.inf
np.fill_diagonal(D, A[:,1])
unq_ids = np.sort(np.unique(A[:,0], return_index=True)[1])
D = D[:,unq_ids]
print(D)
```

This gives

```
array([[0.25,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf, 0.32,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf, 0.45,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf, 0.55,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, 0.77,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, 0.35],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf]])
```

As you can see, the row 4 and 7 doesn't have any distance information, but I am expecting

```
array([[0.25,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf, 0.32,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf, 0.45,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf, 0.55,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf, 0.91,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, 0.77,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, 0.35],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf, 0.82,  inf,  inf]])
```

In fact, I have a more than 10000 pairs of points, so I want to know a fast way in Numpy to first detect duplicates of the destination points, and then "merge" the distance matrix's columns that correspond to the same destination point (please don't use Pandas).

Comment: Stop worrying about fastest, and get it working right first.  For finding duplicates, `unique` is probably your best numpy tool.  It's a less cleear what you mean by `merge`.

Comment: @hpaulj `merge` means to put all elements of the duplicate columns into one column.

Comment: If the coordinates match, by row as well as column, do they add?

Comment: @hpaulj I mentioned the source points are 8 **different** points, so the rows cannot match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [104]: unq_ids = np.sort(np.unique(A[:,0], return_index=True)[1])

In [105]: unq_ids
Out[105]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

With those numbers, just the row/column indices, `D[:,unq_ids]` is just going to return `D` as you filled with the diagonal.

```
In [110]: np.unique(A[:,0], return_index=True, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
Out[110]: 
(array([2.5, 3.7, 4.8, 6.1, 7.3, 8.6]),
 array([1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 6]),
 array([4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 5, 3]),
 array([2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]))
```

`counts` tells us how many duplicates there are, but `unique` does not identify the indices of those duplicates.

In general, `numpy` isn't that good at 'matching' things. We can do matching in `numpy`, but it takes some work.  Pandas has a convenient `group_by`, though I've never tested it for speed.

```
In [112]: np.sort(A[:,0])
Out[112]: array([2.5, 2.5, 3.7, 4.8, 6.1, 6.1, 7.3, 8.6])
In [113]: np.argsort(A[:,0])
Out[113]: array([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 7, 0, 6])
```

We could compare that with the `return_index`,
`array([1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 6])`, to find that `4` and `7` are the duplicates.

```
In [115]: D[:,[4,7]]
Out[115]: 
array([[ inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf],
       [0.91,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf],
       [ inf, 0.82]])

In [117]: A[[4,7]]
Out[117]: 
array([[2.5 , 0.91],
       [6.1 , 0.82]])
```

So with the unique `A[:,0]` values, we can find all 'groups'

```
In [120]: U = np.array([2.5, 3.7, 4.8, 6.1, 7.3, 8.6])
In [123]: for i in U:
     ...:     x = np.nonzero(A[:,0]==i)
     ...:     print(x,A[x,1])
     ...:     
(array([1, 4]),) [[0.32 0.91]]
(array([2]),) [[0.45]]
(array([5]),) [[0.77]]
(array([3, 7]),) [[0.55 0.82]]
(array([0]),) [[0.25]]
(array([6]),) [[0.35]]
```

So now all we need to do is map those onto your `D` (with sorted unique 'indices'):

Answer (score 2):

This solves the problem, although it requires two loops to do so.  I originally created the value-to-column mapping using a comprehension, but that results in duplicates favoring the LAST instance, not the FIRST instance.

To be honest, I'm not sure how this could be useful.  The output array is not square; the columns don't correspond to the rows, because you've removed the duplicated values.  (Your sample data set produces 8 rows and 6 columns.)  So, unless you construct the list of non-duplicated values in their proper order, there's no way for you to pick the array element you want.  Do you see what I mean?  The "2.5" value exists in row 1 (from 0) and row 4, but it's only in column 1.  Column 4 is the "4.8" value.  How will you know that?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[7.3, 0.25],
              [2.5, 0.32],
              [3.7, 0.45],
              [6.1, 0.55],
              [2.5, 0.91],
              [4.8, 0.77],
              [8.6, 0.35],
              [6.1, 0.82]])

mapx = {}
for c in A[:,0]:
    if c not in mapx:
        mapx[c] = len(mapx)

D = np.ones((A.shape[0],len(mapx))) * np.inf
for n,(a,b) in enumerate(A):
    D[n,mapx[a]] = b
print(D)
```

Output:

```
[[0.25  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf 0.32  inf  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf 0.45  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf 0.55  inf  inf]
 [ inf 0.91  inf  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf 0.77  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf  inf 0.35]
 [ inf  inf  inf 0.82  inf  inf]]
```

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned that I want to always merge to the column with the first occurence.

Comment: Your example data shows that, which is why that's exactly what I did.  Note that my actual output matches your "I am expecting" output.